# Why did `exiftool -rotation=0 input.mov` rotate my video?

Tags: windows, video, vlc-media-player, rotate

I have an `input.mov` video file recorded by an iPhone 12 mini. I copied the video to my Windows 10 laptop. When I open the on video on my Windows 10 laptop with VLC, the video plays in portrait mode. I ran the following lossless [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/index.html) command:

```
exiftool -rotation=0 input.mov
```

and now the `input.mov` video file plays in landscape mode with VLC. Why? I thought `-rotation=0` would do nothing.

Comment: Probably because it had a 90 / 270 degree of rotation?

Comment: @TomYan thanks, I see, -rotation=0 is a directly metadata value and not an action value? In other words, running `exiftool -rotation=x input.mov`  several times is the same as running `exiftool -rotation=x input.mov` once, regardless of the value of x.

Comment: Not sure, but IMHO that would be the only case that makes sense, since you are really just modifying some metadata.

Comment: @TomYan I thought that `exiftool -rotation=x input.mov` would add `x` to the rotation value in the metadata, but given the results, you must be right.